# Can't find Oracle Database Driver in Eclipse JAVA Program

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, connection, executable-jar

I am trying to connect to an oracle database in eclipse. I have ojdbc14.jar in a lib folder in the same project and i added it to the build path of my project, so it also resides in the Referenced Libraries directory, but yet i still get an output to the console of "Could not find the database driver"

Myself and another student employee have been trying to get this figured out for the past day and a half, and no one else in our department is experienced in Java and JSP so i thought StackOverflow would be our best bet =)

```
try {
            // Load the JDBC driver
            String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
            System.out.println("Attempting to load the driver...");
            Class.forName(driverName);
            System.out.print("Loaded the driver");

            // Create a connection to the database
            String serverName = " ;) ";
            String portNumber = " ;) ";
            String sid = " ;) ";
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":"
                    + portNumber + ":" + sid;
            String username = "kenne13";
            String password = "**********";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            if (connection != null) {
                return true;
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // Could not find the database driver
            System.out.println("Could not find the database driver");
            connected = false;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // Could not connect to the database
            System.out.println("Could not connect to the database");
            connected = false;
        }
```

Here is the output in the console:

```
    Aug 18, 2011 10:07:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 382 ms
    Attempting to load the driver...
    Could not find the database driver
```

[Here](http://screencast.com/t/f331iamUw) is a screen capture of the code, the error, and my project directories.

Comment: Can you try changing the driver class name with `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`?

Comment: Tryed it, but still catching that ClassNotFoundException and displaying the same error???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm quite sure now that the class name of the driver is `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` and not `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`.

Comment: I changed it but i am still getting the same error??? Did you take a look at my directory structure??? Idk for sure but the prblem might be in there

Comment: Have you added the library to the J2EE module dependencies? This [blog post](http://tuldoksystem.wordpress.com/2007/11/06/adding-libraries-to-a-dynamic-web-application-in-eclipse/) explains how to do it. There are a few ways to add a library in eclipse and not all will add it to the web application when it's deployed.

Comment: And also inside the jar directories, the proper path is through the drivers directory??? So i dont quite understand why i should take out the driver part of the path?

Comment: Your blog post did it!!!! Thank You so much! Now i gotta figure out why i cant connect to the database =/ But atleast I found the driver thanks to you Thank You a thousand times

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Oracle Driver class is: `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`

Comment: I changed it but i am still getting the same error??? Did you take a look at my directory structure??? Idk for sure but the prblem might be in there

Answer (score 0):

Go to the deploy folder(C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps) of your web app and make sure that ojdbc14.jar is there.

Answer (score -1):

In a related post:
[Cannot find Oracle jdbc driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126339/cannot-find-oracle-jdbc-driver)

the problem was solved adding the oracle library in the run path. Have you tried to configure too? (Run/Run Configurations Select your configuration/classpath tab)