# JSTL Remote Datasource Connection Failure

Tags: oracle, jsp, jstl

I am trying to connect to our external Oracle database, but I'm unable to get any error message as to why it's failing.

```
<c:catch var="error">
<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xx.xx.xx:40004:TJUAWSP" user="xxxxx" password="xxxxx" />
</c:catch>
<c:out value="${error}" />
```

Comment: Provide server log on the failure...

Comment: Oh, duh!  However I am unsure of how to do it since I am running a local instance of CQ5.  Let me look for it.

Comment: There we go: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver not found by day.commons.datasource.jdbcpool

Comment: you can also check whether you have added the right `jar file` for the driver download here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html

Comment: See Similar solved problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126339/cannot-find-oracle-jdbc-driver